# Excision for Relative de Rham Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I recently learned in Bott-Tu about the notion of relative de Rham cohomology, which is defined as follows:

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $S\subset M$ is its (embedded) submanifold, we define the cochain complex $\Omega^*(M,S)$ by $$\Omega ^q(M,S)=\Omega ^q(M)\oplus\Omega ^{q-1}(S),\,d(\omega,\theta )=(d\omega,\omega\vert_S-d\theta).$$ The cohomology group of this cochain complex is called the **relative de Rham cohomology group** and are denoted by $H^q(M,S)=H^q_{dR}(M,S)$.

The cochain complex $\Omega^*(M,S)$ is just the mapping cylinder of the cochain map $\Omega^*(M)\to \Omega^*(S)$ induced by the inclusion, so there is a long-exact sequence $$\cdots\to H^q(M,S)\to H^q(M)\to H^q(S)\to H^{q+1}(M,S)\to\cdots.$$  Also, it is clear that if $M,N$ are smooth manifolds and  $S\subset M$ and $N\subset R$ are their submanifolds, every smooth map $f:M\to N$ such that $f(S)\subset R$ induces a cochain map $\Omega^*(N,R)\to\Omega^*(M,S)$ by pullback, and hence  linear maps between the relative cohomology groups. So the relative de Rham cohomology behaves pretty much like the relative singular cohomology. I, therefore, suspected that the two groups are actually isomorphic;  but I had no clue how to prove it, so I lowered my sights and asked whether excision holds. By excision, I mean the following:

> *If $U,V\subset M$ are open sets and $M=U\cup V$, the inclusion $\iota:(U,U\cap V)\to (M,V)$ induces isomorphisms
>   $$\iota^*:H^q(M,V)\xrightarrow{\cong}H^q(U,U\cap V).$$*

Proving excision first looked very doable, for I could easily prove the injectivity of $\iota^*$ by using a partition of unity. But I got stuck at proving surjectivity. **Does anyone know whether $\iota^*$ is surjective, and if it is surjective, how to prove it?**

---

Some observations

- The long exact sequence for relative de Rham cohomology arises from the short exact sequence $$0\to \Omega^{*-1}(S)\to \Omega^*(M,S)\to \Omega^*(M)\to 0,$$ whereas the singular version arises from the ses of the form $$0\to S^*(M,S;\mathbb{R})\to S^*(M;\mathbb{R}) \to S^*(S;\mathbb{R})\to 0.$$ Thus the long exact sequence of pairs is not available. (If it were the case, five lemma will immediately imply that "singular relative= relative de Rham")
- Because of this, if one is to prove that "singular relative= relative de Rham" via the five lemma, we need to construct a homomorphism $I:H^p_{dR}(M,S)\to H^p(M,S;\mathbb{R})$ (the RHS is the singular relative cohomology). One obvious candidate is   $$I:[\omega,\theta]\mapsto\left([\sigma]\mapsto \int _\sigma \omega\right).$$ This, however, is not well-defined. Indeed, let  $\alpha\in\Omega^1(M)$ be any 1-form such that $d\alpha\neq 0$ at some $x\in M\setminus S$. Because $[d(\alpha,0)]=0$ in $H^0_{dR} (M,S)$, one should have $I[d(\alpha,0)]=0$. But then $\int _x d\alpha=d\alpha(x)=0$, contrary to our hypothesis.

Comment: Can't you use de Rham's theorem which states that this is the case for nonrelative cohomology ? Then use the long exact sequence of pairs ?

Comment: @Max Thank you for your comment. I just made an edit to elaborate on why it is not so easy  to use the long exact sequence of pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative de Rham cochain complex $Ω(M,S)$ is simply the homotopy fiber of the pullback map $Ω(M)→Ω(S)$ (computed as the mapping cocone).

Likewise, the relative singular cochain complex $S(M,S)$ is the homotopy fiber of the restriction map $S(M)→S(S)$ (computed as the kernel of a surjective map).

Thus, the natural weak equivalence of functors $Ω→S$ induces a natural weak equivalence (possibly a zigzag) $Ω(M,S)→S(M,S)$ of homotopy fibers, as desired.

Comment: Shouldn't the mapping cone compute homotopy *co*fiber?

Comment: @Ken: Yes.  But one is a shift of the other, adjusted now.

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that cofiber is a shift of the other. Can you kindly give me a reference where I can learn such stuff?

Comment: @Ken: See, for example, Theorem 7.1.11 in Hovey's Model Categories, in the general case of stable model categories.  In the case of chain complexes, one can also see it directly by inspecting the two constructions.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and answer. I will have a look at it. I greatly appreciate your help.